# Floating Action Button not removed from MainActivity.java - causes error

Tags: android

When I delete the default email Floating Action Button from the Design View, it causes build errors.   Specifically, an error that says "Cannot Find Symbol Variable fab"

At which point I had to go into the MainActivity.java file and manually remove the reference to the fab causing the error......This code

What do I need to do so that the MainActivity.java file is properly updated to reflect changes in the Design View?

```
`
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
`
```

Comment: did you comment the code you pasted above?

Comment: You have to manual remove design code and source code, then after build code. There is no shortcut key that remove widget from layout and remove source code directly.

Comment: Hello, am a little confused about this question but if you want to remove the FAB all you need to do is remove from the `activity_main.xml` and also delete the java code from `MainActivity.java`. After doing this, you shouldn't get anymore errors

Answer (score 0):

Remove the FloatingActionButton code from your `layout` xml and also remove from `MainActivity.java` class. Remove entire below code from `MainActivity.java` class.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the FAB all you need to do is remove the Widget code from the `activity_main.xml` and also delete the java code from `MainActivity.java`. After doing this, you will not get anymore errors.

Remove this from your `MainActivity.java`

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

and remove this from `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```